# validate jquery setting max and min for validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a question about val() using javascript and I wanted to find out if anybody could tell me how to set a min max parameter for val(). Basically I want to check if my inputs age is 1 but smaller than 3. Here is the code:

```
 if ($.trim($("#age").val()) > 1 < 3) { 
     // Code goes here
 }
```

I know the code above is not working. How can I set that validity max and min parameters?

Comment: Now ask another question where you post the HTML and ask how to do it with HTML5 pattern attribute and native validation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for ages 1-3 also allowing for age 1 and 3

```
var _age = $.trim($("#age").val());
if ( _age >= 1 && _age <= 3) {
    // Code goes here
}
```

You may have issues since age is currently a string. You can force it to an integer by doing this.

```
    var _age = $.trim($("#age").val());
    _age = parseInt(_age);
    if ( _age >= 1 && _age <= 3) {
        // Code goes here
    }
```

The last should work just fine

Comment: Personal preference but I prefer to do _`x` in range_ as `0 <= x && x <= 1` or _`x` outside range_ as `x <= 0 && 1 <= x`, just to keep all of the comparison operators going the same direction

Comment: Agreed, I just modified what was currently there. It would be better practice to keep them going the same way. If this answer works, please accept it.